# Node.js: Error deploying to Heroku when added googleapis package

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-api

I added to my package.json the previous line, it worked perfect locally but when I deploy to heroku it is rejected.

> Error: No compatible version found: inherits@'^2.0.1'

**package.json**

```
"googleapis": ">= 0.0.0",
```

**Heroku deploy log:**

```
-----> Deleting 2 files matching .slugignore patterns.
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Requested node range:  0.8.21
-----> Resolved node version: 0.8.21
-----> Downloading and installing node
-----> Restoring node_modules directory from cache
-----> Pruning cached dependencies not specified in package.json
-----> Exporting config vars to environment
-----> Installing dependencies
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/googleapis
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/googleapis
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/googleapis/-/googleapis-1.0.9.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/googleapis/-/googleapis-1.0.9.tgz
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.10
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gapitoken/0.1.2
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/multipart-stream/1.0.0
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/2.37.0
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gapitoken/0.1.2
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gapitoken/-/gapitoken-0.1.2.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/multipart-stream/1.0.0
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/multipart-stream/-/multipart-stream-1.0.0.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gapitoken/-/gapitoken-0.1.2.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/2.37.0
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.2.10
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.37.0.tgz
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.10.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/multipart-stream/-/multipart-stream-1.0.0.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.37.0.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.10.tgz
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jws/0.0.2
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sandwich-stream
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jws/0.0.2
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk/1.1.1
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
       npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jws/-/jws-0.0.2.tgz
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
       npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sandwich-stream
       npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: inherits@'^2.0.1'
       npm ERR! Valid install targets:
       npm ERR! ["1.0.0","2.0.0","2.0.1"]
       npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/tmp/build_63edc9a5-ba9f-4380-9d67-15fc37cf717f/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:679:10)
       npm ERR!     at /tmp/build_63edc9a5-ba9f-4380-9d67-15fc37cf717f/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:594:10
       npm ERR!     at saved (/tmp/build_63edc9a5-ba9f-4380-9d67-15fc37cf717f/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
       npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
       npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
       npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
       npm ERR! or email it to:
       npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

       npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
       npm ERR! command "/tmp/build_63edc9a5-ba9f-4380-9d67-15fc37cf717f/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_63edc9a5-ba9f-4380-9d67-15fc37cf717f/vendor/node/bin/npm" "install" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_63edc9a5-ba9f-4380-9d67-15fc37cf717f/.npmrc" "--production"
       npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_63edc9a5-ba9f-4380-9d67-15fc37cf717f
       npm ERR! node -v v0.8.21
       npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.11
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved upgrading Node version and npm. Node was 0.8.21 and npm was 1.2.10.

**Upgraded package.json:**

```
"node": "0.10.30",
"npm": "1.3.6"
```

In fact, seems like npm version is irrelevant for [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support):

> There is no need to specify an npm version, as npm is bundled with node.